# error TemplateNotFound: hello.html from flask

Tags: python, flask

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 64, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: hello.html
```

script of app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

APP = Flask(_name__)

@APP.route('/')
def hello():
      return render_template('hello.html')

if _name__ == '_main__':
    APP.debug=True
    APP.run()
```

My directory structure:

```
app/
├── app.py
├── app.py~
├── static  
│   └── style.css
└── template
      ├── hello.html
      └── hello.html~
```

Comment: Just the traceback tells us absolutely nothing. What code are you using? Where are the files located? What does your directory setup look like?

Comment: script of app.py:

from flask import Flask

from flask import request

from flask import render_template

APP = Flask(_name__)

@APP.route('/')

def hello():

      return render_template('hello.html')

if _name__ == '_main__':

    APP.debug=True

    APP.run()

And hello.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Hello</title>
    
</head>

<body>

      Hello 

</body>

</html>

Comment: So where is `app.py` located? Where is the `hello.html` file located?

Comment: I have an App folder in which I created a static folder that contains the .css style and template folder with which I put hello.html and the mother "App" record it there's app.py

Comment: The template folder does not go inside the static folder. It goes **next** to the static folder and `app.py`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters template folder doses not in static folder ,it is in APP folder  and also static folder in App folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default template directory name is *`templates`*, plural. You are missing the `s` at the end.

Alternatively, tell Flask to look at the different directory name:

```
APP = Flask(_name__, template_folder='template')
```

Comment: @kaio: Your test code + the directory name change works for me. Did you restart the server?

Comment: thanks when i restart the server it works :) thanks a lot